# SQL Script does not insert float value to table

Tags: sql, ef-code-first

I ran into a problem when populating database in Code-First approach. I created blank migration and in `Up()` method I added simple SQL script to insert concrete values to table. Unfortunately, both `Id` and `Name` values are inserted properly, but values for `Value` column stay the same for all the rows and equal 1. Do you have any idea why it happened?
These are SQL scripts I used:

```
    Sql("INSERT INTO ActivityFactors (Id, Name, Value) VALUES (1, 'Thing1', '1.2')");
    Sql("INSERT INTO ActivityFactors (Id, Name, Value) VALUES (2, 'Thing2', '1.375')");
    Sql("INSERT INTO ActivityFactors (Id, Name, Value) VALUES (3, 'Thing3', '1.55')");
    Sql("INSERT INTO ActivityFactors (Id, Name, Value) VALUES (4, 'Thing4', '1.725')");
    Sql("INSERT INTO ActivityFactors (Id, Name, Value) VALUES (5, 'Thing5', '1.9')");
```

Comment: why are you enclosing float value with single quotes?

Comment: Also, can we see what column type "Value" is?

Comment: @Pons I might have left it that way while experimenting with this sql script. Nevertheless, without those single quotes, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @suecarmol column is of type float

Comment: Have you tried changing the column type to decimal?

Answer (score 3):

Convert the column name `Value` datatype to `decimal(18,2)`.

DECIMAL(p,s): Exact numerical, precision p, scale s. 
Example: decimal(5,2) is a number that has 3 digits before the decimal and 2 digits after the decimal.